# Formatting a date input using simple_form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, date, input, simple-form

I have a `date` type field in my database.

Here's the view code I'm using:

```
# Using 'as: :string' to avoid those three dropdowns rails generates.
= f.input_field :start_date, as: :string, class: 'form-control datepicker'
```

When saving a date I use a jquery plugin that shows a calendar and writes in a date like: `11/05/2013`.

But when editing the same record, the input is populated with a value `2013-05-11`.

How can I make it so simple_form actually respects my date format defined in `en.yml`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's what you need :

```
f.input :my_date,
        :as => :string, 
        :input_html => { :value => localize(f.object.my_date) }
```

PS : This was the first link in google [search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/XcU4qx63TnM) :)

Comment: It is also worth knowing that you can specify format for localize function e.g. `localize(f.object.my_date, format: :short)`

Comment: You can also provide formats such as: `localize(f.object.my_date, format: "%-m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Now *this* is the first link in my google search. : )

Comment: This does not work with HTML5 date fields e.g. on a mobile Safari browser. The HTML5 date field expects the value to be in yyyy-mm-dd format. Are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: @morgler,  localize(f.object.my_date, format: "%yyy-%mm-%dd")

Comment: @rb512 Thanks, but in this case I don't need localize at all. Is there a way to display the date in the local format (e.g. dd.mm.yyyy), but still give the date field its value in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: Guys, where is this locale(f.object...) comes from? Or rather how do I write the date format locale? I have tried something like this:        `= f.input :my_date, as: :string, input_html: { value: localize(f.object.my_date) }`

But, threw _undefined method `date_from' for nil:NilClass_ error.

Comment: @bir_ham: f comes from the simple_form builder ```= simple_form_for @object do |f|```

Comment: `= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'datepicker', value: localize(f.object.date_of_birth, format: "%d/%m/%Y") }, label: _('Date of Birth'), hint: 'date-format: dd/mm/yyyy'`

Answer (score 9):

I created this class which makes it easy to do this:

```
f.input :my_date, :as => :date_picker
```

Add this class to your lib/ folder and be sure to include it (or configure it to autoload):

```
class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input
    value = @builder.object.send(attribute_name)
    input_html_options[:value] = case value
                                   when Date, Time, DateTime
                                     format = options[:format] || :medium
                                     value.to_s(format)
                                   else
                                     value.to_s
                                 end

    input_html_options[:class] ||= []
    input_html_options[:class] << "date_picker_input"
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  end
end
```