# Saving date from datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

In my form i'm using datepicker plugin. it works fine, and my form code looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @person do |f|
    = f.input :born, input_html: {class: "datepicker"}, as: :string
    = f.input :died, input_html: {class: "datepicker"}, as: :string
    = f.submit
```

However, params I get are in a form of string, like "2015/02/04" and they are not saved in the database. with classic input params look competely different. How can I make these params save into the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761080/formatting-a-date-input-using-simple-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date string looks like `2015/02/04` which is default format of datepicker plugin, but to save it to the database you need to change it to `2015-02-04` format. So you need to do something like this in the action

```
params[:born] = params[:born].gsub("/", "-")
```

**or**

you need to pass an option when you are initializing the datepicker plugin, like give below

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({    
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-YYYY'
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wasnt me who downvoted, i actually used your answer to solve my problem thanks! only it should be yy and not YYYY

Answer (score 0):

```
2.1.0 :049 > d = "2015/02/04"
 => "2015/02/04" 
2.1.0 :050 > Date.parse(d, "%Y/%M/%d")
 => Wed, 04 Feb 2015
```

Using this date will be saved